# Different php versions in VPS for every account. How?

Tags: php, cpanel, whm

i have a virtual dedicated server:
PHP version 5.3.1
PHP Handler : suphp

What i need is to have different php versions (5.2.17) in some of my accounts. Is this possible to be done and how can i do this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I've just done [this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=multiple+php+linux+suphp) which brings up [this result](http://www.top-web-solutions.com/apache-with-multiple-php-versions.html). Please get into the habit of searching before asking `:)`

Answer (score 2):

you can install many php versions on apache

http://blog.servergrove.com/2011/08/22/how-to-setup-multiple-php-versions-on-apache/

good luck!

Comment: This is possible only if i change the handler to fastcgi? Can i have different php versions for every account with suphp? Thanks